# how to receive TLS Handshake error in chrome websocket code

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

```
1015    TLS Handshake   Reserved. Indicates that the connection was closed due to a failure to perform a TLS handshake (e.g., the server certificate can't be verified).
```

see: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#Browser_compatibility) 
example chrome(Version 71.0) return 1006 error, firefox(version 64.0 (64-bit) )1015:

```
<script>
try{
    var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://self-signed.badssl.com/");

    websocket.onopen = function (event) {

    };
    websocket.onclose = function (event) {
        var reason;
        alert(event.code);

    };
    websocket.onmessage = function (event) {

    };
    websocket.onerror = function (event) {

    };
    }
    catch(err){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors cannot be caught with catch, the callback recieve's the error. You can follow this [guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/websockets_handling_errors.htm)